# Splitting keys from values into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function to convert a `.json` file to an array:

```
function jsonToArray($file) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    print_r($json); }
```

This yields an array like this:

```
Array (
[field1] => value1
[field2] => Array
    (
        [subfield1] => subvalue1
        [subfield2] => subvalue2
        [subfield3] => subvalue3
    )
)
```

To interface with existing code, I need these arrays with the fields and values split, like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => field1
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => subfield1
                [1] => subfield2
                [2] => subfield3
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => subvalue1
                [1] => subvalue2
                [2] => subvalue3
            )

    )
)
```

The code I came up with works if this structure is maintained for all usage but as that can't be guaranteed I need another solution. I'm sure it's something relatively simple, I just can't crack it. Any hints or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
    $arr = array ('field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => array(
            'subfield1' => 'subvalue1',
            'subfield2' => 'subvalue2',
            'subfield3' => 'subvalue3'));

function array_values_recursive($ary)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( $ary as $k => $v ) {
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = $v;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst[] = array_values_recursive($v);
        }
    }
    return array_values($lst);
 }

 function array_keys_recursive($ary)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( $ary as $k => $v ) {
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = ($k);
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst[] = array_keys_recursive($v);
        }
    }
    return $lst;
}
echo '<pre>';
$arr1 = array();
$arr1[] = array_values_recursive($arr);
$arr1[] = array_keys_recursive($arr);
print_r($arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you: [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) that and a little of *foreach* would do the magic.